# Shimano RD-5800 and 7 speed cassette

Tags: shimano, derailleur, cassette, derailleur-rear

Is Shimano RD-5800 rear derailleur compatible with a 7 speed cassette?

Answer (score 2):

Nope. The RD-5800 is the previous generation 105 level derailleur that works with 11 speed shifters and cassette.

<strike>You need a derailleur intended specifically for 7 speeds. The only 7 speed models Shimano makes are in the Tourney range.</strike>

Apparently, at least for 7-9 speeds, Shimano road derailleurs are compatible with 7-9 speed shifters as the combination of shifter cable pull and derailleur ratio will index the cage correctly. This does not work for 11 speed though.

Comment: I don't think so. The derailleur is not indexed (unlike the shifter) such that new a derailleur is compatible with old (7-speed) shifters. See http://blog.artscyclery.com/science-behind-the-magic/science-behind-the-magic-drivetrain-compatibility/

Comment: 11-speed derailleur can be installed together with shifter indexed for 7 speeds, but the combination will not index correctly for 7-speed cassette. Check "derailleur ratio" under the link you posted. 10-speed road derailleur or any Shimano derailleur for 9 or less speeds will work.

Comment: Yes the shifter does the indexing, and pulls a certain amount of cable per sprocket, but the derailleur also has a *derailleur ratio* which is how much it moves the cage per cable pulled.  AFAIK there used to be compatibility across different Shimano speed drivetrains, but 11 speed broke that.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus 5800 was superseded by R7000 a week ago, so it's not really the last 105 anymore.